# AJAX with Load and selector doesn't load scripts but nothing I found seems to work

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, selector

Yesterday, thanks to the help here, I learned how to load AJAX'ed content and keep the page the same.
However, the script tags didn't load.
After some research, it seems that when you use a selector in .load it doesn't load the  tag stuff.
The easiest solution for me would be something that would just execute them and keep the functionality but I tried many things and none seem to work.

I tried .getScript on .ajaxComplete etc.. (I seriously can't remember all I tried, I've been searching the web all day)
I do sometimes get like an alert box but when I want to initialize prettyphoto, it doesn't work.

This is the code I have for the AJAX thanks to another user here:

```
 function ajaxPageLoader(request_url) {
    console.log("Content loading from : "+request_url);
    $("#ContentContainer").load(request_url+" #ContentContainer", function() {
        window.history.pushState({}, "", request_url); // update current url in browser.
        console.log("Content loaded");
    });
}
```

I understand this code, but can't seem to find a way around it with the damned selector :)

Alternatively, is there another way altogether?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code
You have to bind your field id with request which will be your output of service call

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
      type: "{POST/GET}",
      url: request-url,
      data: "",
      contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json/xml",

      success: function(result){
          $("#ContentContainer").html(result);
        },
       error:function(result){
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Hmm I don't have any field. It's basically just this to bind:

    $(document).on('click','.ajax_link',function(){
        ajaxPageLoader($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });

I am probably misunderstanding you, sorry. 
I put this code in the function, so it's not on document.ready. I'll dig a bit deeper.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong just yet though.

But this code will only replace #ContentContainer div? I can't seem to figure out the piece of code that makes sure only the div is change for the same div of the other page.

Comment: A problem I had is that when clicking a link, it would change the page altogether. But, when I changed it and just called it in a function it wouldn't change the content to the DIV even when I change the "url: request-url" to the page directly